# jQuery issue not working the hyperlink

Tags: jquery

My link to forwarding jsp not working

Something wrong in not working - I need help with this :

```
$("<td>").addClass("labelSearchData")
    .append("<a>")
    .attr("href", "/mng/admin/DetailCustomLabelSummary")
    .text(checkValue(node, "label"))
    .appendTo(trow);
```

Original code :

```
$("<td>").addClass("labelSearchData")
    .text(checkValue(node, "label"))
    .appendTo(trow);
```

Comment: note that $("") is probably not selecting anything.., as also append("") is not Doing anything at all..

Answer (score 0):

`.append()` returns the object that you appended to, not the object that you're appending. So your code is calling `.attr` and `.text` on the `<td>`, not the `<a>` that you're adding. And when you call `.text()`, that replaces the `<a>` that was appended. Try:

```
$("<td>").addClass("labelSearchData")
    .append($("<a>", {
        href: "/mng/admin/DetailCustomLabelSummary",
        text: checkValue(node, "label")
    }))
    .appendTo(trow);
```

Comment: If you want a pop up window, add `target: "_blank"` to the properties of the `<a>`